# Bayesian inference for probability of finding extra-terrestrial intelligent life as more negative evidence is collected

Tags: bayesian, astronomy

Consider the problem of estimating the *number* of discoverable extra-terrestrial civilizations (in our galaxy, say), or the related problem of estimating the *probability* of discovering such a civilization in some given time frame.

The proper way to make such estimations is via Bayesian statistics, where you have prior information about the relevant parameters (number of stars, number of inhabitable planets per star, probability they emit detectable radio signals, etc.) and then *revise* such probabilities as new data are collected (change in number of inhabitable planets, negative results of radio searches, etc.).

Such prior information is generally presented as the *Drake Equation*, in which such relevant parameters are multiplied together to get the number of potentially discoverable extra-terrestrial civilizations.  It can be extended, given some measure of the search effort, volume of space that can be monitored, etc., to yield the *probability* of finding such extra-terrestrial life.

I have heard astrobiologists at scientific conferences and numerous popularizers on TV (e.g., Neal deGrasse Tyson) quote enormously large numbers for the potentially discoverable civilizations, and how given the short (~50-year) effort of SETI (Search for Extra-Terrestrial Intelligence) searches, the negative results are "like dipping a tea cup into the ocean, finding no whales and erroneously concluding that there are no whales in the ocean."

But is this true?

I have not seen the proper Bayesian statistical method applied to this problem.

**Some questions (astronomical but primarily statistical)**

1. Is there a recent peer-reviewed scientific/statistical paper where the proper Bayesian estimation methods have been applied to this problem?  ([This 30-year-old paper is the most relevant one I've seen, so far.](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1984QJRAS..25..435W&db_key=AST&page_ind=0&plate_select=NO&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_GIF&classic=YES))
2. As astronomers find more and more candidate planets, does that mean to a statistician there is an *increase* the estimated probability we'll find extra-terrestrial life or *decrease* that probability, given that decades of negative results then imply life is not discovered on a *larger* number of planets?  (Of course one must make some assumptions about coverage, and so on to answer this.)
3. If, as some SETI workers claim, our negative search results don't significantly lower the prior estimation given by the Drake Equation (see the "whale" discussion, above), then will a statistician conclude that doubling, or even increasing our search effort by one or two orders of magnitude similarly not matter, i.e., not change our estimates significantly?
4. Given our current estimates for the terms in the Drake Equation and some reasonable extrapolation of search effort (and hence search volume of space and duration of civilization), how long would would a statistician conclude we need to search and at what effort such that the continued negative results would imply the probability of ever finding extra-terrestrial life is negligibly small, say $P \leq 10^{-5}$?

Comment: I remember reading this a few years back. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.3835.pdf

Comment: MikeWise:  Very helpful citation, but limited to just one (important) factor in the Drake Equation:  the probability of the emergence of life *of some kind*.  Given that amidst the hundreds of millions of species that have arisen that only one *intelligent* (and hence discoverable) species has arisen, I suspect that the chance we find extra-terrestrial life is extraordinarily low.  But I'm open to evidence and proper statistical reasoning.

Comment: Well debatable. I personally think that this stage of development (where intelligence is limited to serially recordable symbol sequences and we use thermodynamiccally inefficient processes to compute) is brief and the only one we can recognize. The next wave is just too fast and small and low emmission for us to notice.

Comment: MikeWise:  You seem to agree that the chance we detect extra-terrestrial life is indeed very small (in part because of low emissions).  But my central question/concern remains:  negative results for decades should revise our estimates we'll ever find life.

Comment: This paper by Dienes might be remotely relevant. It might help to clarify the distinction between Neyman Pearson statistics (and their hidden absurdities) pitted against principled Bayesian treatment. Author provides some nice examples and discussions. http://web.archive.org/web/20160110225652/http://www.lifesci.sussex.ac.uk/home/Zoltan_Dienes/Dienes%202011%20Bayes.pdf

Comment: It isn't clear to me that this question is on topic here. It seems to be more about the astrobiology than about the statistical issues. It might help to make whatever *statistical* question you have more central. You might also be better asking this elsewhere (eg, the [astronomy.SE] SE site).

Comment: xeon:  Thanks but we statisticians agree upon the supremacy of Bayes over Neyman-Pearson (and incoherencies such as "fuzzy logic").  My question centers on applying the proper Bayesian reasoning to a field where it seems like every month or so astronomers are touting evidence (e.g., new planets) that they claim is *increasing* the chance we'll find extra-terrestrial intelligence, but somehow (as far as I can tell) don't revise *downward* such estimates as each year of failure passes.  Just trying to keep them honest!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I see your point. It is like being stranded on an inhabited island (with water & food) and you want to know if the probability being saved increases as time passe or not. Depending where island is, the probability might decrease (remote island) or increase (nearby ship routes, aborigen visits).

Comment: @xeon:  Exactly.  Or another analogy:  You're searching for a ringing alarm clock in a house consisting of 10 (assumed identical) rooms, each with a cupboard with ten drawers that might hold a ringing alarm clock.  You walk into one room and hear no alarm clocks and make your statistical estimations about the presence of such a clock in the *entire* house.  But then someone points out that there were in fact *100* candidate drawers in each room (when you heard no clock).  Does your estimate of the probability of a ringing alarm clock *anywhere in the house* go *up* or go *down* (or remain)?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Can we put the question this way: What is the simplest possible model under which we don't observe alien signals (or those clock alarms in a house)?

Comment: @xeon:  I view the essence of one problem being (under reasonable conditions) whether finding that given there have been far more potential sites (planets) than previous assumed, do our negative results *increase* or *decrease* the probability of finding life.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my back of the envelope calculation. It does not answer your questions but is too big to fit in a comment.

Suppose $p$ is the probability of life on an earth like planet and there are $N$ earth like planets. Then the probability of life anywhere else (apart from Earth) is

$$1 - (1-p)^{N-1}$$

The answer to your question depends on how $p$ and $N$ grow over time. In a really simplistic model, suppose we check $k$ planets and find no life except us. Then we might estimate $p = 1/k$, so the probability becomes

$$f(k, N) = 1 - (1-1/k)^{N-1}$$

Now you can check that if $k$ and $N$ are large then the partial derivatives with respect to $N$ and $k$ satisfy $|f_N| < |f_k|$ which implies that if you substitute $k \rightarrow k+1$ and $N \rightarrow N+1$ then the value of $f$ goes down.

This in turns means that if you discover one more earth-like planet and find no life on it, then indeed the probability of finding life in the universe actually decreases.

However, I'm not sure whether this has any value towards answering the practical part of the question. Maybe we just don't know how to detect aliens yet?

Comment: Thanks.  A good basic start.  I don't think the "we don't know how to detect aliens yet" point is quite relevant, at least to the core of my question.  Let me *define* or restrict consideration to aliens that emit radio waves.  Even under this condition, it may be that the more planets we find (without radio emissions), the *less* likely it is there are other "radio-able" civilizations.  That to me would be a *fascinating* conclusion, and one the SETI enthusiasts would have to contend with.  As far as I can see, they don't.  (But I'm open to learning if someone has.)